# NoMethodError using Rails 4.0 and nested forms with cocoon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, cocoon-gem

I'm learning to use Rails 4.0 and I'm using [Cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) to create nested forms for a simple Polling app.

The user should be able to add a new question and then add as many answers as they'd like.

I've got the nested forms working but when I try to save the Poll and i'm getting an error that says ``` NoMethodError in PollsController#create - undefined method ``answer' for #<Poll:0x007fba59a70dd0> ```

Here's the relevant information from my Polls_Controller:

```
before_action :set_poll, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def create
    @poll = Poll.new(poll_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @poll.save
        format.html { redirect_to @poll, notice: 'Poll was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @poll }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @poll.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

private
def poll_params
  params.require(:poll).permit(:question, :expires, answers_attributes: [:id, :answer, :_destroy])
end
```

Polls Model

```
class Poll < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :answers, :class_name => "Answer"

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

    validates :answer, presence: true
end
```

And the Answers model

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :poll
end
```

Here are the two .erb partials containing the Poll form and the Answer (nested) form.

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@poll) do |f| %>
  <% if @poll.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@poll.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this poll from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @poll.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %> 

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :question %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :question, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="answers">
      <%= f.fields_for :answers do |answer| %>
        <%= render 'answer_fields', f: answer %>
      <% end %>  
        <div class="links">
          <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Answer', f, :answers, class: "btn btn-default add-button" %>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :expires %><br>
      <%= f.datetime_select :expires %>
    </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

_answer.html.erb

```
<div class="nested-fields form-group">
      <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :answer %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :answer, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "remove answer", f, class: "form-button btn btn-default" %>
</div>
```

I've been staring at this for far too long and even though it's a simple idea, my brain isn't seeing the issue. Any ideas?

**Edit** Here is my Schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20151104213600) do

  create_table "answers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "answer"
    t.integer  "poll_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "answers", ["poll_id"], name: "index_answers_on_poll_id"

  create_table "polls", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "question"
    t.datetime "expires"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

Comment: is the answer text field named answer on the Answer model??

Comment: @aledustet, I have updated the OP to show the schema.rb file. It is named "answer"

Comment: is the partial named _answer_fields.html.erb or _answer.html.erb as you put on your question?

Comment: it is called _answer_fields.erb -  and it's rendering properly. I think I've found the error. When I remove `validates :answer, presence: true` from the Poll model, it saves everything properly. That said, I'm unsure on how to modify that so it does still validate the answers to avoid empty fields being submitted.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this problem myself, and by pre-building the associated relation, it worked like a charm, doing this:

```ruby
def new
  @poll = Poll.new
  @poll.answers.build
end
```